# How to bind RecyclerView and ViewPager to work correctly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have some list of images that displaying use RecyclerView and if tap to any image, then open new window of image and in this window can swipe use ViewPager. Is it possible to implement? I started but can not cope...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext, Images.loadImages);
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_preview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#313130"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PreviewActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/preview_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PreviewActivity**

```
public class PreviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.preview_pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PreviewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.Holder> {
    private int[] mItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] itemList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list, null);
        return new Holder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Images.loadImages[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).resize(400, 750).into(holder.view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.mItemList.length;
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView view;

        Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            view = new ImageView(mContext);
            view = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_test", getAdapterPosition());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_view_pager.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**PageFragment** - here I don't know how to make correctly

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "id_test";
    private int pageNumber;
    private Uri source;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        pageNumber = i.getExtras().getInt("id_test");
        source = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.test.nico/drawable/" + Images.loadImages[pageNumber]);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);

        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);
//        resultView.setImageURI(source);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**PreviewPagerAdapter**

```
class PreviewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int imagesCount = Images.loadImages.length;
    private int[] images = Images.loadImages;

    PreviewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(images[position]);
    }
}
```

also **view_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stub"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and just for example **Images**

```
class Images {
    final static int[] loadImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img_01,
            R.drawable.img_02,
            R.drawable.img_03,
            R.drawable.img_04// etc.
    };
}
```

Help me to understand please.
Issue - can not implement so: if tap to image in MainActivity - this image has to open in PreviewActivity full screen and there I can make scroll right and left use ViewPager to browse the next or previous image in the array.
Now, when i tap to image, and if use in **PageFragment** `resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);` - then always open firts image in my array, and if use `resultView.setImageURI(source);` - then open true image but if swipe - always show this one image.
Sory for my english =)

Comment: Please explain more clearly what issues you have with your current implementation.

Comment: @Okas sure see i update my question

Comment: I still can not understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: this app have only 2 activities (windows), in the first window you can browse images that displaying recyclerview, in the second window you can scroll right and left the images use ViewPager, but I cant to implement ViewPager correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. In my `PreviewActivity` i have to add my image position to viewPager use method `setCurrentItem`:

`viewpager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id_test"));`